# How to properly set ADODB.Recordset.Filter property for a DateTime value?

Tags: vba, vb6, excel, adodb

I have an ADODB 2.x recordset and am trying to apply a filter to a DateTime column/field in the recordset.

I do not know how the has configured their international date format settings in Windows.  From lots of googling, I am not entirely sure if the windows date format settings determines the required date format for the Filter property, or whether it is always expected in US date format.  (Of course, the MS documentation makes no note of this.)

So, how does one properly write this line of code, so I don't have to worry what date format the user has configured in Windows:

```
rs.Filter = "StartDateTime >= " & dteStartDate
```

...where **dteStartDate** contains both a Date and Time component.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the filter needs to be in identical format as the value in the recordset.  I just ran into the same issue with a recordset from a MS SQL server.  the recordset contained a date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

This failed:

```
CalendarRS.filter = "DateField = #" & datevalue(DisplayDate) & "#"
```

Even if the date matched, no records were in the filtered recordset.  When checked, the value stored in CalendarRS.filter was "DateField = #08/29/2014#"  Note that this contains forward slashes and that the order is different (MM/DD/YYYY)

This succeeded:

```
CalendarRS.filter = "DateField = #" & year(datevalue(DisplayDate)) & "-" &  right("00" & month(datevalue(DisplayDate)),2) & "-" &  right("00" & day(datevalue(DisplayDate)),2) & "#"
```

When checked, the value stored in CalendarRS.filter was "DateField = #2014-08-2014#".  This returned the correct filtered recordset.

For a full date and time, you need to do the same thing and add hour, minute, second.

```
 CalendarRS.filter = "DateField = #" & year(datevalue(DisplayDate)) & "-" & right("00" & month(datevalue(DisplayDate)),2) & "-" & right("00" & day(datevalue(DisplayDate)),2) & " " & Right("00" & Hour(datevalue(DisplayDate)),2) & ":" & Right("00" & Minute(datevalue(DisplayDate)),2) & ":" & Right("00" & Second(datevalue(DisplayDate)),2) & "#"
```